# Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () con React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, error404

Como estan? Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Estoy tratando de subir un proyecto que hice con React a un host, pero al subirlo me me aparece dos veces este error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" en la consola y por lo tanto no carga la página, y hace referencia a dos background-image.
[image: Error 404 de las imágenes]

El código donde utilizo el background image es el siguiente, en CSS:

```
.container {
background-image: url('/src/assets/bg.png');
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 100vh;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
```

}

Y luego el mismo url (con otro nombre de imagen) para el mismo selector pero en un media query.

No sé como solucionar el error, si me ayudan estaré super agredecido!

Comment: Parece ser que en el ambiente en donde estás subiendo tu proyecto ("host") no existe `/src/assets/bg.png`  entonces tu explorador web no puede bajar la imagen. Asegúrate de que tengas un servidor que disponga estos datos a tus clientes. Esto está fuera del tema de React y tiene más que ver en la arquitectura de tu host y como dispone los archivos que tus páginas necesitan.

Comment: Hola Fran, muchas gracias por responder. Perdón, pero no logro entender como solucionarlo, tengo esas imágenes pero no entiendo en donde alojarlas entonces

Comment: Una solución sería alojarlas en algún lugar de internet como [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) y pon de `background-image` la ruta a tu imagen, por ejemplo, la imagen de tu usuario está guardada en `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9abfbc01ff0437024be0764e391bb273?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG` si pones eso se cargará tu gravatar del perfil de stack overflow en tu aplicación de React.

Comment: Muchas gracias Fran! Lo pude solucionar a eso utilizando cloudinary, te lo agradezco un montón!

Comment: Con mucho gusto, la solución más habitual es que el servidor que sirve tu página web sea el mismo que sirve las imágenes. Puedes buscar tutoriales o videos al respecto, en ese caso podrías usar rutas relativas como en tu ejemplo original.